# PHP subtract minutes from unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

i need to subtract 30 minutes from current unix timestamp.

I print with this function for print unix timestamp:

`echo time(); //ouput: 1412856148`

Now I need to print `time()` with subtract 30 minutes.

how do print this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the DateTime Object

```
$time = new DateTime();
$time->modify('-30 minutes');
echo $time->format('U');
```

Comment: if i need to print `$row['timestamp'];` from database subbtract 30 minutes, `new DateTime()` how to work ?

Comment: The DateTime object needs the @ sign for a Unix timestamp. Just as follows: new DateTime('@' . $row['timestamp']);

Answer (score 2):

time() returns the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 seconds so all you have to do is figure out how many seconds are in 30 minutes and then subtract that number from the timestamp.

```
echo (time() - (30*60));
```

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp represent the seconds from the 01.01.1970.

```
echo time()-30*60;
```

Therefore you can just substract the seconds.
You can also format this as a date or something:

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a", time()-30*60);
```